# Run Cygwin software on Linux

Tags: x11, windows, wine, cygwin

My professor has some software that he wrote that runs on Unix-like systems. Either on Windows via Cygwin or on MacOS, it uses X11 on both platforms.

Is there any way for me to run it on Linux? He refuses to port it to Linux and is not releasing the source code. Running Cygwin on Wine just seems a little silly.

Comment: what do you think about porting this to freebsd ? because macosx is basically freebsd , i guess that way should be relatively easy .

Comment: If the software runs on Unix and Cygwin, it should be easy to port to Linux. If he doesn't want to share the code to someone who is able and willing to do that, you're out of luck going that route. Ask him to put the software on GitHub so others can do this even if he doesn't want to spend any time on it it himself.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the reasonable thing would be asking him to compile it to Linux as he really opposes to release the source code (shouldn't be big deal though if he wrote it "posixly"),

Cygwin is a "layer" that provides Unix API under Windows and Wine is a "layer" that provides Windows API under Linux.  Since in the end of the day the software written for Cygwin end up being a windows software, the actual solution seems to be in the direction of using Wine indeed.  Although I agree it sounds silly it is the way to go given the constraints.  Another viable option would be more like a cannon ball to kill a fly: Using a windows virtual machine under Linux.

Just curious: What does this software do that it is so special?  Couldn't you write your own?

Comment: I've asked him multiple times to compile it for Linux, but he says no every time.

The software is a simulator for the Terasic DE0 boards. One simulator is for the VHDL and another for the assembly.

Comment: I would choose the "cannon ball" option: a Windows VM running on Linux with cygwin installed in, notably because once the work is done, this can be shared. (and also because I already run some other software in such way).